# Rails populate text area based on drop down menu selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, templates

I have a model (named Template) that contains email Templates; the model simply has a short name for the Template (:name) and then the full template itself (:content).  The user should be able to select a template from the drop down and then a text area should display the content of the Template.  This should happen before the form is submitted.

I think one way I can do this is with jQuery.  So far in my form I'm detecting the selection and then populating a text area with a test message.  I'm not sure how to then go back to the selection and get the content of the template into the text area.  Would greatly appreciate any help.

Here is my form:

```
<%= form_for :message, :url => send_prod_status_path(@incident), :html => {:method => :get} do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :template %>    <%= f.collection_select(:template_id, ::Template.all, :id, :name, prompt: "Choose a template") %>
  </div>

<script>
  $("select").change(function(){
    $("textarea").text("Test")
  });
</script>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :prod_status %>
    <%= f.text_area :prod_status %>
  </div>



  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Send ProdStatus" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
~
```

EDIT: This is Rails 3.2 if that matters

Comment: You would need to use AJAX to get the information from the database based on the `template_id` selection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make an AJAX call to your server asking for the actual `Template.text`.

Something like (code simplified and no tested):

```
# templates_controller.rb
def show
  template = Template.find(params[:id])
  render :text => template.content
end

# form.html.erb
<script>
  $("select").change(function(){
    $.get( 
      "/templates/" + $("select option:selected").attr("value"), 
      function(data) {
        $("textarea").text(data);
      }
    );
  });
</script>
```

#### Update: full JS approach

You also can store all the `Templates` info in a JS object and use it to refresh the `textarea`.

Something like (code simplified and no tested):

```
# form.html.erb
<script>
  var templates = [<%= ::Template.all.map(&:to_json).join(",") %>];

  $("select").change(function(){
    var template_id = $("select option:selected").attr("value");
    var template_content = get_template_content(template_id)
    $("textarea").text(template_content);
  });

  function get_template_content(template_id){
    // to be implemented ...
    return template_content;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This worked.  Although I had to make a new action as I already had a show action for this controller.  Maybe this is a silly question, but is this the quick and dirty way or is this the right way to do this type of thing?

Comment: This solution has not anything of dirty. You can reuse the same action and respond differently using the [respond_to](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rendering-xml-and-json-data) helper.

Comment: @irlrobot check my update for a no-extra-ajax-call-needed solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways to do this:

1. Send all the data (having the mapping of Template Id and Template content) to the front end on page load in the form of a json object in javascript.
2. Send only the Template Id and name and populate the text area with the template content by making ajax requests each time the selection in the dropdown is changed. This is a better approach if you have a lot of templates.